# How to enable the MMU in an ARMv8A TF-A based bare-metal environment

Tags: arm64, bare-metal, mmu, armv8

I recently enabled the MMU in lower ELs (EL1/EL0) in our ARMv8A bare-metal test environment that runs on top of TF-A. Turning on the MMU requires translation tables to be created, which is a highly formatted data set and difficult to create from scratch. Turned out that the TF-A library has a very well-equipped set of functions to ease the creation of these tables for any translation regime and to enable the MMU. But it took me some time to get to the required sequence. Hence I am asking this question and following it up with my own answer for the same. I intend this question to be an easy hit for folks searching for the same information, which will put them in the right direction fast and hopefully save some time.

This would be useful for developers who want to create their own MMU tables using the TF-A library for custom uses. There is ARM-provided documentation for this topic which is qiite good. This answer is intended to be a start point that points to all the required concepts for performing the task.

The function and macro names could change in future TF-A release, but I expect the concepts used to remain unchanged.

Answer (score -1):

Please find below the steps one can follow to use the TF-A library to create the required translation tables and enable the MMU.

**Required concepts -**

1. The main concept to keep in mind is that the TF-A library maintains each set of translation tables for a given translation regime as a "context".
2. Multiple contexts are expected to be created by the software using TF-A.
3. There is documentation available for this topic in the *xlat-tables-lib-v2-design.rst* document inside the *amp-atf/docs* folder of the TF-A release.
4. The *amp-atf/lib/xlat_tables_v2* folder contains code that shows the example use of the translation table related library functions
5. There are two structures defined in TF-A for translation table related actions - *xlat_ctx_t* and *mmap_region_t*. These are actually typedefs which create a type out of a *struct xlat_ctx* and *struct mmap_region* respectively (defined in *amp-atf/include/lib/xlat_tables/xlat_tables_v2_helpers.h* and *amp-atf/include/lib/xlat_tables/xlat_tables_v2.h*).
6. The *struct xlat_ctx* is created to contain the information for a translation context (ie. any one translation regime). Each context is of course expected to contain multiple MMU region mappings. The *struct mmap_region* is created to contain the info for each such region
7. The library has functions and macros that abstract out the creation, population and use of these structure objects. So one needs to think in terms of calling the right functions from the library in the right order to work with these structures.
8. One translation context called *tf* is already created and used by the TF-A codebase itself. The code in the *amp-atf/lib/xlat_tables_v2* folder works with this context.

**Additional concepts -**

1. Static and dynamic mapping - The library separates out the creation of the translation tables in memory from the programming of the core registers to point to these tables. The addition of the MMU regions to the memory before the translation tables are created is referred to as *static* mapping. In addition, the library also supports MMU regions to be added to memory *after* the translation tables have been created. This is referred to as *dynamic* mapping.
2. There are two versions of the xlat table library - *xlat_tables* and *xlat_tables_v2*. The version 2 supports dynamic mapping and is more flexible. In general both versions are still active parts of the TF-A codebase at this time.

**Software flow - (4 steps)**

1. Create a new translation context in memory (a new struct xlat_ctx object)

   ```
   - A macro REGISTER_XLAT_CONTEXT is defined for this
   - arguments - a name for the new context, max. number of mmap regions to be statically allocated for, max. number of xlat tables, virtual address range and physical address range. Usually, these would be defined in the platform-specific include files for the overall project. 
   - Lets assume that the name *name1* is passed to this macro. 
   - A *struct xlat_ctx" object with the name - *name1_xlat_ctx* will be created by this macro
   ```
2. Add the required MMU regions to the context (new struct mmap_region objects)

   ```
   - Create a *struct mmap_region* object out of the basic memory addresses and ranges
   - A macro MAP_REGION is defined for this
   - eg. *mmap_region_t tmp = MAP_REGION(base_pa_addr, base_va_addr, region_size, attributes)*
   - The attributes specify all the important qualities of the region like RO/RW, device/normal etc. There are macros for these values already available in TF-A (inside *amp-atf/include/lib/xlat_tables/xlat_tables_v2.h*). Multiple attributes can be ORed together and passed as the argument
   - After the region is created, it is to be added to the translation context through the *mmap_add_region_ctx* function
   - eg. mmap_add_region_ctx(&name1_xlat_ctx,&tmp);
   - Multiple calls to MAP_REGION and mmap_add_region_ctx would be required in general to map all the required regions.
   ```
3. Ensure that the translation regime of the new context is set

   ```
   - this is stored in the variable *xlat_regime* of the xlat_ctx_t object
   - there are macros already defined for all the regimes
   - eg. name1_xlat_ctx.xlat_regime = EL1_EL0_REGIME;
   ```
4. Consume the above information and create translation tables in the required format in another region of memory

   ```
   - The function init_xlat_tables_ctx() is available for this
   eg. init_xlat_tables_ctx(&name1_xlat_ctx)
   ```
5. Perform TLB invalidation and program the core registers (MAIR0/1, TTBR0/1_ELx, SCTLR_ELx etc.) to point to these newly created translation tables and **turn on the MMU**

   ```
   - There are different functions for each EL available in the library for this - 
   - *enable_mmu_el3(attributes), enable_mmu_el2(attributes), enable_mmu_el1(attributes)*
   - The attributes here refer to the attributes of the newly created translation table - where it is placed in memory and whether it is shareable across multiple PEs in a multicore system. 
   - eg. enable_mmu_el1(XLAT_TABLE_NSH);
   ```

Right! With the above steps, it should be possible to start executing code and perform data in the required EL with the MMU turned on.

I hope this answer provides some amount of headstart to folks who want to use the TF-A library to create new translation tables for their custom uses. Please do let me know if there is any additional information that can be added to this answer to make it more useful.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is really helpful, but I have a question. Where do I implement this API? Can I do it during runtime in a EL2 context? Or do I need to do it through TF-A at either BL1, BL2, BL3-1, etc stages? In my case I just simply want to allow EL2 to have access to a big chunk of registers, without much concern on security

Comment: I did it through TF-A by adding to our port of the TF-A code. I think some of the defines used above would need to change for the EL2 regime, but the same sequence, executed somewhere within the TF-A boot stages, perhaps, BL3-1, will perform the required init for EL2 tables